# Reading a Western about stud poker and need some clarification -?

Tags: seven-card-stud

In a book's dialog, there are two characters: Smoke and Delaney (he's the kid)

I don't know what "draw short" means.

When it says "Here's yours and I'm drawing mine", I assume this means that cards are being dealt, but there may be a bit more to this.

> It was Smoke’s deal. With the final card, there was a thousand-dollar
>   pot.  The kid had a pair of jacks showing. Smoke had a possible
>   straight. But Smoke had been plunging for a long, long time. The kid
>   was used to his empty bluffs.
>
> “Make it a thousand,” said Smoke. **“I’ll
>   draw short.”**
>
> “A thousand, and another thousand,” responded Delaney.
>
> **“Here’s yours and I’m drawing mine.”**
>
> “Call,” said Delaney, thrusting
>   out an IOU.
>
> Smoke had his filler.
>
> That was the first big pot Delaney
>   had lost. It did not bother him.

From L. Ron Hubbard, [*The Toughest Ranger*](https://books.google.com/books?id=EuvJGpkBo3kC&pg=PT62&lpg=PT62&source=bl&ots=pHIcri-ADk&sig=AoIyAvsVrw2Zj7waiwq8MKejlQE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRwPSW44TfAhWT51QKHS-jBckQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: This is extremely unclear. Can you re-write the question to make it more coherent and readable?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this is drawing chips from the pot and creating a "light" pile to cover the bet as they are both out of chips...